# Jmeter cookie manager gives only partial data

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, session-cookies, performance-testing

I am a little bit new to performance testing.

When I execute the request in jmeter it gives below cookie data:

[image: jMeter]

> Cookie Data: 
>   connect.sid=s%3AfPrGL1_53rGjjHbTFTjUYdEjmQgb4NT4.fDW1TeCFzzlNOs2eVWGAzu7zmHXfoi5Mr5EAGJ7b5U8**

But in browser post request it requires more.

[image: Browser]

> Cookie:
>   _gat=1; _ga=GA1.2.1134157642.1501677880;
>   _gid=GA1.2.1756641378.1501677880;
>   connect.sid=s%3AOL8HjrZzfe3N9wWNPJcAd3gVMh6VKTRQ.8pHyh2A34mZ3cR3SmM5Scfbs0s2iMxJnB1hMfbZ0rag**

Here is my test script structure.

```
Test Plan
  Thread Group
    Cookie Manager
    Login To application
    And do some submit action
  Summary report
```

Note: I've changed configuration in `jmeter.properties` and getting same result.

```
CookieManager.save.cookies=true
```

Comment: See similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519883/jmeter-cookie-manager-doesnt-store-all-cookies

Comment: how does `Set-Cookie` header looks in responds that sends cookie to the client?

Answer (score 0):

set the following in jmeter.properties (in bin folder) it will prevent ignoring cookies in different origin.

```
CookieManager.check.cookies=false
```